# Choice of Linux

Tags: linux, mono

Which version of Linux would be my best choice if I want to use it as a development platform for both Java EE and MONO?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that Novell are the main contributors to Mono, OpenSuSE. It is likely the Mono stack will be more stable in their distribution, as it is a flagship function.

Comment: +1, Using the [SuSEStudio][1] might help here a lot.

 [1]: http://susestudio.com/

Comment: Agreed, I thought OpenSuse, but the X driver I needed didn't work on OpenSuse, so I'm using Ubuntu 9.04. Works really well. :)

Answer (score 3):

Any distro will work as long as you install the required packages. Avoid obscure distros that may miss packages, go for Debian or Ubuntu or Fedora or one of the biggest ones and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't matter. Mostly it comes down to the packages you install.

I prefer Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using Ubuntu Karmic 9.04 and runs well, like in any Distro.

Comment: 9.04 Karmic? 9.04 is Jaunty and 9.10 is Karmic.

Comment: yes sorry i'm upgrading is 9.04 Jaunty and 9.10 Karmic, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter! But, since its the Novell guys pushing Mono and OpenSUSE both, probably, and only probably, atleast psychologically you will feel better using that combination.